# looking for a program for linux to view the call stack of my program

Tags: linux

looking for a native linux program that lets you view the call stack.

Comment: the call stack of what ? A program you wrote which is compiled in debug mode ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always run it in `gdb` debugger, stop at a point and inspect call stack.

Comment: Specifically, with the `bt` command.

Answer (score 0):

As in 'gdb' - the GNU Debugger?

If not, what are you after - in what context do you want to see the call stack?

Answer (score 0):

Very limited information in your question but you can use "addr2line" to translate stack trace to the code of your application (assuming you have an executable with debug symbols).